In Google Workspace, how to identify app from client_id
I have a customer with many Google Workspace users who sign in to lots of websites using SSO with workspace. If an admin is signed in to admin.google.com they can see the list of accessed websites from Security > Access and data control > Api Controls > Accessed Apps > View list. That list displays a name of the app and the ID, e.g. 532352704633-6pkces9iboppp465idnovkcqtlsa8j7t.apps.googleusercontent.com.

If I click into one of the apps I get more details, sometimes including an App URL, e.g. https://www.figma.com/. Is there a way to find the Name and App URL of these apps programmatically, i.e. without just browsing the admin page in browser? I have the list of client_id values but I want to programmatically map them to a Name and Url for reporting.

